# Laravel: Changing Production Error Page

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 4, the `Illuminate\Exception\PlainDisplayer` object is responsible for displaying the production error page (i.e. the error page Laravel uses when `debug` is set to false).

This `PlainDisplayer` is hard coded to load the `plain.html` file from the composer package.

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/PlainDisplayer.php

return new Response(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/resources/plain.html'), $status, $headers);
```

I want to customize the production to match my application's design/theme, but it's not 100% clear what the best/preferred way of doing this is.  As mentioned, the plain displayer is hard coded to load a package file that will change during updates, so I can't directly edit `plain.html`.

Is there a vendor approved way of doing this?  A non-vendor approved way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register error handlers in your application by calling `App::error` and passing it a type-hinted callable. The generic error handler (which defers to a `PlainDisplayer` when `debug` is false) is only called if no other suitable error handler has been registered.

http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-errors